# Debugging with QtCreator

Tags: ros, qtcreator, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to switch from Eclipse to QtCreator (the indexing on Eclipse is very poor after our recent switch from fuerte to indigo). And while I have indexing and building working wonderfully in QtCreator, I cannot get debugging to work at all. I found the following article on this forum:

http://answers.ros.org/question/96586/putting-it-together-where-do-ides-come-in-with-ros-development/

I did the following with QtCreator 3.0.1:

1. Switch Projects/Build & Run / Run
2. Set run configuration as the name of my executable
3. Set program arguments
4. Set working directory to ~/workspace/bin ( a newly created folder)
5. Checked my run environment (the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_ROOT variables are correctly set)

And then I tried to debug and I get a small error window titled "Unknown error" with no message. Debug never reaches the first line of the program. But if I execute the program by hand, it works fine.

Any ideas on what I have not configured? In general, I should be able to debug with qtcreator, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204263/debugging-with-qtcreator/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be a QtCreator problem (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator-plugin-cmake/+bug/1299441). Removing the CMakeLists.txt.user file fixes the issue temporarily... upgrading to Creator 3.1.0 may solve the issue.

---

Originally posted by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) with karma: 100 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I do is: after opening my CMakeLists.txt file, right click on the root folder named "Project", run Cmake, and then for arguments I use:

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:=Debug
```

for debugging with QtCreator and

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:=Release
```

for the release version.

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1